# Why are singular "elliptic" curves bad for crypto?

Tags: elliptic-curves

Consider the algebraic curve given by a short Weierstraß equation $y^2=x^3+ax+b$.

If $4a^3+27b^2=0$, then there are repeated roots of the right-hand side $x^3+ax+b$. How are these repeated roots bad for a discrete-logarithm-based cryptosystem?

Comment: A related question [Why do the discriminant and primality of the group order of an elliptic curve affect security?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/86882/18298)

Answer (score 7):

When a Weierstraß equation $y^2 = x^3 + Ax + B$ over $\mathbf F_p$ has a null discriminant, then it does not define an elliptic curve: it is a singular curve. In that case, it means the polynomial $x^3 + Ax + B$ has a double or triple root $x_0$ and the point $(x_0, 0)$ is a singular point. All the non-singular points still define a group law with the regular construction as in an elliptic curve.

With a change of variable, you can always come back to these two cases:

- $y^2 = x^3$, then there are exactly $p$ non-singular points and there is an efficient map to the additive group of $\mathbf F_p$ where the discrete logarithm is trivial.
- $y^2 = x^2(x-1)$, then there are $p+1$ or $p-1$ points and there is an efficient map to the multiplicative group of $\mathbf F_{p^2}^*$ (which has $p^2 - 1 = (p-1)(p+1)$ elements) where the discrete logarithm is way easier to compute (but not as easy as the previous case).

In both cases it is very bad for crypto.

Answer (score -3):

To find A,(-3 (n^2)),to find B ,
(-4(A^3))/ 27 )^(1/2).Then IF n is 1, A = -3,   B = 2 ,then ( -2×1) is the maximum local x.Then y at this point is zero,
[ -8 + (-3×-2) +2 ]^(1/2) = zero. If  x is then -1 ,y is 4, the square root of 4 is 2.Also turns  out if any fractional square times a whole number square
,-2 + [(.5)(.5) (1)(1)] =-1.75.Then x at -1.75 ,

Comment: Hi Tony, we're not so much interested in any direct calculations as a clear indication why and how. Please amend your answer or remove it.